Adding text to image and then downloading on react native expo
I'm researching if it is easily possible with React Native Expo.
I want to edit an image from assets folder and add some text overlay to it and share it to people. Think of it like a postcard with a greeting message on it.
How would I add text to an image and download it to share with people? I'm not looking for detailed code, just for an explanation on how to get started and what packages to use. I tried using expo-pixi and expo-gl. image-manipulator can only edit the image but cannot write text. So please I need help.
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
